# Save the user activities from login facebook or OAuth to database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

i have tried to login with facebook in firebase . So how i save the user information such as : email , username , ... to database . and i don't know what the next step to know or save when  they did some activities for example, they clicked to order some products in my website .then the next time they login with the old facebook . if i am be admin how i fetching the data from database ? (@nuxtjs/firebase) how should i do next? i have tried looking for 2 months ago.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
        <v-card>
          <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
              <v-form @submit.prevent="loginUser">
                <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
                  <v-text-field
                    type="email"
                    error-count=""
                    placeholder=""
                    label="email"
                    append-icon="mdi-email"
                    v-model="email"
                    outlined
                    color
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
                  <v-text-field
                    type="email"
                    error-count=""
                    placeholder=""
                    label="password"
                    append-icon="mdi-password"
                    v-model="password"
                    outlined
                    color
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
                  <v-btn medium elevation="" color="primary" type="submit"
                    >login</v-btn
                  >
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
                  <v-btn
                    medium
                    elevation=""
                    color="primary"
                    type=""
                    @click="loginWithFacebook()"
                    >log in with facebook</v-btn
                  >
                </v-col>
              </v-form>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    async loginUser() {
      try {
        const response = await this.$fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          this.email,
          this.password
        )
        console.log(response)
        this.$router.replace({ name: 'test1' })
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },
    async loginWithFacebook() {
      try {
        const provider = new this.$fireModule.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
        let authData = await this.$fire.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        console.log(authData)
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with login you can check the status of the user (loguedIn or logued out) with something like this:

```
this.$fire.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => { 

  if (user) {          

    this.$store.state.user.loguedin = true;  

    this.loguedin = true;

  } else {

    this.loguedin = false;    
    this.$router.push('/login');

  }

});
```

Comment: ok thank you , in the next step i don't know how to explained 555 . if they changed the new username something like that , i just want to know how do we recognize that user ? for example: they logged in to my website , and order 1 product then they change the username? So ,  i just know the logic handle the user's activity in database . That i have tried authentication in  firebase first

Comment: Ask one thing at a time and be as clear as possible on the problem you want to solve. Once you solved that problem you can ask a new question, not here on the comments.

Comment: ok thank you everyone